# Delete dynamically added form field

Tags: jquery

How do I delete the last dynamically added field http://jsfiddle.net/6mzjfmwd/

```
$('#addContact').click(function() {
        $('.row').append(
            '<br><div class="col-md-6">contact type</div><div class="col-md-6">contact</div>'
            );
        return false;
    });

$('#removeContact').click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".row").remove();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS to include a wrapper div around the contact:

```
$('#addContact').click(function() {
    $('.row').append(
        // Observe the change here
        '<div class="contact"><br><div class="col-md-6">contact type</div><div class="col-md-6">contact</div></div>'  
        );
    return false;
});

$('#removeContact').click(function() {
    $(".row").find(".contact").last().remove();
    return false;
});
```

**Fiddle**   : http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/6mzjfmwd/2/

Updated fiddle: Without using the `br` tag. Instead using CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/6mzjfmwd/4/

Comment: Great! It is working with some mistake: I dynamically add fields (many of them), and then delete them (all of them), and the <br> tags remain

Comment: Just move the `br` tag inside `<div class="contact">`

Comment: Or you can totally remove the `br` tag and add a CSS like this `.contact{
    margin:10px 0;
    
}`

Comment: Read the comment in the code which says `// Observe the change here`

Comment: your answer is correct but the question is "How do I delete the last dynamically added field" no "add a field for delete last field"

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the last div of the row

```
$('#removeContact').click(function() {
    $(".row div").last().remove();
});
```

If you want to remove all the data of the last contact added:

```
$(".row").find("br:last").nextAll("div").remove();
$(".row").find("br:last").remove();
```

Comment: Funny, this code is removing all my other divs from the bottom to the top

Comment: krlzlx - your code is closest to the truth. But, I have other divs with col-md-6 class which should NOT be removed.

Comment: I'm not using your col-md-6 class to remove the last contact. My code is removing the last added contact with the addContact function you provided. If you have more code, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `siblings()` method

```
$('#removeContact').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".row").remove();
    return false;
});
```

Example Fiddle: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6mzjfmwd/1/)**

**Note:** `closest()` method will fetch ancestor elements only.

`siblings(".row")` will return all the sibling `div.row` elements. From there you can delete your selected `div.row` element alone.

Comment: this will delete all the rows

Comment: Yes by using `eq` selector we can target the selected element from the total collection of sibling elements.

Comment: please answer accordingly this answer will further confuse OP

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
$('#removeContact').click(function() {
    $(".col-md-6").last().remove();
    $(".col-md-6").last().remove();
    $("br").last().remove();
    return false;
});
```